# error 403 ACCESS FORBIDDEN! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to open a file that is stored in my local storage. But everytime I clicked OPEN, this error 403 comes up. I think this happened when I tried adding a delete button and created complications with my php code.

Please check this code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","annualdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM asean_japan WHERE agency='Rail'");

?>
<table class='page'>
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Agency</th>
    <th>FileName</th>
    <th>FileType</th>
    <th>Date Received</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agency']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['filetype']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
    <td><a target='_blank' href='../annual/indicators/" <?php echo $row['filename']; ?>"'>OPEN</a></td>
  </tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `href='../annual/indicators/"` means that you are going 1 directory up from where this php file is located. Are you sure that the file you are referencing is located in that?

Comment: yes it is the right folder where my file is located.

Comment: Is you password blank for the post or is that the issue?  Or it could be your local folder permissions.

Comment: I posted an answer about this. I tried every way to make it run without errors. But I don't understand why it suddenly ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting my table inside the php tag and it suddenly works. What could be the problem with this?

```
echo "<table class='page'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>FileName</th>
<th>FileType</th>
<th>Date Received</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['agency'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filetype'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a target='_blank' href='../annual/CPA/" . $row['filename'] . "'>OPEN</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a target='_blank' href='../annual/indicators/" <?php echo $row['filename']; ?>"'>OPEN</a></td>
```

That line was invalid. It would create a link like this:
http://myhost.com/annual/indicators/%22%20somefile.pdf%22 where %22 is urlencoded value for " and %20 is urlencoded value for whitespace.

You can use it this way:

```
<td><a target='_blank' href='../annual/indicators/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>'>OPEN</a></td>
```